# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skimage' in jupyter notebook

Tags: python

I have already installed skimage and I can import it in conda command and spyder.

```
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import skimage
>>>
```

However, under same virtual environment,  I got this error in Jupyter notebook.  Not sure why it only NOT working in jupyter notebook. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the Jupyter notebook is using a kernel with that same Anaconda environment. You may need to register an IPython kernel in the environment. See [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-different-environments) for instructions on how to do that. Here is the relevant code.

```
# Activate your conda enviornment
source activate myenv
python -m ipykernel install --user --name myenv --display-name "Python (myenv)"
```